# sum on column for records returned from another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering what the best way to do this is:

I have a table `voldata(vol_id, key_id, dte, volume)` that will have hundreds of thousands of entries. there are thousands of unique `key_id` entries. Each `key_id` entry has about 100 `dte` entries (ie, date). So the table might look something like this:

```
vol_id key_id dte volume
...
186303  K_DXNRTDZL  2013-09-01  2900
186304  K_DXNRTDZL  2013-10-01  4400
186305  K_DXNRTDZL  2013-11-01  4400
186306  K_DXNRTDZL  2013-12-01  4400
...
186433  K_WXDNKG3O  2014-03-01  8100
186434  K_WXDNKG3O  2014-04-01  8100
186435  K_WXDNKG3O  2014-05-01  6600
186436  K_WXDNKG3O  2014-06-01  8100
...
186338  K_X4TSU3RD  2014-01-01  5400
186339  K_X4TSU3RD  2014-02-01  6600
186340  K_X4TSU3RD  2014-03-01  8100
186341  K_X4TSU3RD  2014-04-01  8100
```

I have another table `catkeydata(catkey_id, cat_id, key_id)`. Each `cat_id` (category) is made up of potentially hundreds of `key_ids`. So this table stores data like:

```
catkey_id cat_id key_id
7305    C_B3ZRB0QR  K_DXNRTDZL
7306    C_B3ZRB0QR  K_X4TSU3RD
7307    C_B3ZRB0QR  K_G7TBKU83
7308    C_B3ZRB0QR  K_8X0L681N
7312    C_B3ZRB0QR  K_WXDNKG3O
```

ie, the category C_B3ZRB0QR is made up of the 5 `key_ids` shown there.  I want to be able to SUM the `volume` from the `voldata` table for a given date and a given category.  So, I'll be requesting the full list of `key_ids` that make up a given category then I want to sum the volume for those keywords for a specific date.

Is there an easy/one-line way to do that without looping through all the keywords in the category?  Thanks!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I figured it was going to be pretty basic, but I'm just learning SQL so I'm not exactly sure how to put that specific query together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT SUM(volume) FROM voldata INNER JOIN catkeydata ON 
voldata.key_id = catkeydata.key_id WHERE cat_id = ‘C_B3ZRB0QR’ 
AND dte = ‘2013-09-01’;
```

Comment: If you are going to show a SQL statement to a beginner, you should at least give it a reasonable format.

Answer (score 0):

Would also bring in the Categories that have no children and give visibility to that.

```
$query = "SELECT c.CAT_ID, SUM(v.VOLUME) FROM CATKEYDATA AS c LEFT JOIN VOLDATA v ON c.KEY_ID = v.KEY_ID AND v.DATE = '2014-06-01'";
```